node.js require returns a string
I created an Electron project with Vite.
And I imported Electron from the file to be used in the Worker.
No Electron object was returned, only the Electron installation path.
How do I get an Electron object?
I saw the question below, but I didn't understand it.
node.js require returns a string instead of module object

file structure


file contents
src/main/index.ts
  import { app, shell, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron'
  import { join } from 'path'
  import { electronApp, optimizer, is } from '@electron-toolkit/utils'
  import icon from '../../resources/icon.png?asset'
  import creatWorker from './worker?nodeWorker'

  function createWindow(): void {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 900,
      height: 670,
      show: false,
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      ...(process.platform === 'linux' ? { icon } : {}),
      webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      sandbox: true
      }
  })

  mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
      mainWindow.show()
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
      shell.openExternal(details.url)
      return { action: 'deny' }
  })

  if (is.dev && process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL']) {
      mainWindow.loadURL(process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL'])
  } else {
      mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'))
  }
  }

  app.whenReady().then(() => {
  electronApp.setAppUserModelId('com.electron')
  app.on('browser-window-created', (_, window) => {
      optimizer.watchWindowShortcuts(window)
  })

  ipcMain.on('ping', () => console.log('pong'))

  createWindow()
  creatWorker({}).on('message', (message) => {
      console.log(`\nMessage from worker: ${message}`)
  })

  app.on('activate', function () {
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
  })

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit()
  }
  })

src/main/worker.ts
import test from 'electron'
console.log(typeof test)
// return 'string'
console.log(test)
// return '/Users/x/Documents/code/my_project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron'




Try import * as test from 'electron'

@Konrad The import result is that the default property and numeric properties from 0 to 104 are imported.
The default property is a string that represents the path to Electron.
Numeric properties from 0 to 104 are assigned one letter to each digit of the Electron path string above.
And there was no Electron API object as expected...
